# Arrays not filling in as expected in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I just started trying to learn C++ yesterday, and one of my goals for the near future is to make a matrix multiplication function.

Before trying that, I wanted to get a feel of how arrays work, so I made a simple program that is supposed to make two arrays that represent (mathematical) vectors in 3D space and take their dot product. Below is the code that I wrote.

```
/*Initializing two vectors, v1 and v2*/
int v1[3] = { 0 }; 
int v2[3] = { 0 };

int sum = 0; //This will become the sum for the dot product

int i=0; //counter for the following loop
for(; i<3; ++i)
    v1[i] = v2[i] = i+1; //This should make both vectors equal {1,2,3} at the end of the loop
    sum += v1[i]*v2[i]; //Component-wise, performing the dot product operation

std::cout<< sum <<std::endl;
return 0;
```

When the code is done running, the output is supposed to come out to be 1*1 +2*2 +3*3 = 14

However, the output is actually coming out as 647194768, which doesn't seem to make any sense. I heard from some friends that in C++, if you aren't careful about initializing the arrays, then some crazy stuff happens, but I'm completely dumbfounded how something this simple could mess up so badly.

Could you provide some deeper insight into why this is happening, and what about C++'s logic causes this?

Comment: BTW, an editor which indents C++ for you can help a lot here. You've indented your statements the way you _want_ them grouped, but an auto-indent will show you how they're _actually_ grouped.

Answer (score 3):

You are accidentally putting the `sum +=` line outside the for loop. This is because you have no braces on the loop. So only the first line `v1[i]...` is included in the for loop. Change it like this:

```
/*Initializing two vectors, v1 and v2*/
int v1[3] = { 0 }; 
int v2[3] = { 0 };

int sum = 0; //This will become the sum for the dot product

for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    v1[i] = v2[i] = i+1; //This should make both vectors equal {1,2,3} at the end of the loop
    sum += v1[i]*v2[i]; //Component-wise, performing the dot product operation
}

std::cout<< sum <<std::endl;
return 0;
```

Note the use of braces `{ .. }` around the for loop statements. Now this gives the correct answer: 14.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask deeper insight here i am writing some explanation of your code

```
int v1[3] = { 0 }; 
int v2[3] = { 0 };
```

Initializing v1 and v2 with 0,

```
int sum = 0; //This will become the sum for the dot product
```

Here you Initializing sum with 0 (GOOD)

```
int i=0; //counter for the following loop
for(; i<3; ++i)
    v1[i] = v2[i] = i+1; //This should make both vectors equal {1,2,3} at the end of the loop
    sum += v1[i]*v2[i]; //Component-wise, performing the dot product operation
```

Here you make mistake as you did not provide {..} compiler will consider first list in loop statement. like below

```
v1[0] = v2[0] = 0+1
v1[1] = v2[1] = 1+1
v1[2] = v2[2] = 2+1
```

Now second line will come in picture,
Note that now i is become *3*.

```
sum += v1[i]*v2[i];
```

Here, you try to access invalid location of an array (4th one)
that's the reason why you got ***647194768***

You got junk value nothing else

---

Correct code is already given by metacubed, so I am not writing here,
best of luck for you further study.

Comment: What is the point of putting the counter outside of the loop?

Comment: @juanchopanza, Hay bro i just explain what joe had written in question, nothing else

Comment: Give me one reason for -1, so that i will never repeat same mistake in future :)